# Default directories for python and pip packages are different

Tags: python, django, path, pip, virtualenv

I already had pyhton installed in my system at this location:

```
 which python
/usr/bin/python
```

I later installed pip using easy_install and then used pip to install virtualenv and django. The default path for these packages turned out to be different from where python is installed.

```
which virtualenv
/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
```

will these difference of directories affect the running of python in collaboration with these packages?

How do I change the default python directory to correspond with those of the packages? will link (`ln -s`) work?

Comment: Your virtualenv use your python by itself! when you create a new virtualenv it create a link to default installed python! you can find it in `bin`,`include`,`lib` directories!

Comment: Thanks Kasra! Would this also apply for django package installed in the same path /usr/local/bin whereas puthon is installed at /usr/bin?
Also I dont see any ~/.bash_profile file in my ~ directory, should I create one with PATH variable?

Comment: Sorry i cant figure out what you mean by same path, if you install your Django in a virtualenv environment your django will use of virtualenve python version! (your system python)!

Comment: Also as a good recipe for learn programming you can try all the ways! ;)

Comment: I didnt install the django from the virtualenv enviroenment. I installed it before, and its located at the same path: /usr/local/bin.
Do i uninstall this django version and install one from virtualenv itself?

Comment: Yep, indeed! you need to install a new django for your virtualenv!